# Proof request - Lemma (Non-continuous ODE solutions of $u_t + A(u)_x = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

**Lemma - Protasis :**

> Consider the PDE $u_t + a(u)u_x = 0$. Now, let $A'(u) = a(u)$. The PDE expression can be written as $u_t + A(u)_x = 0$. For this equation to hold, under the sense of distributions, it means that :
>   $$\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty[u\psi_t +A(u)\psi_x]\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t=0$$
>   This expression is equivalent to :
>   $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_a^bu(x,t)\mathrm{d}x+A(u(b,t))-A(u(a,t))=0,\quad \forall a,b$$

**I would like to request a proof to the protasis above if possible, which means a proof for the equivalence of the $2$ expressions.**

(This is mentioned as a theoritical exercise-protasis proof in "Walter A. Strauss - An Introduction to PDEs")

Comment: Which section is this under Strauss?

Comment: @CheeHan Section 14, the exercises at the end (at least in the Greek Version).

Comment: One may add an intermediate step, which is the conservation law $u_t + A(u)_x = 0$ in local form. The latter is both equivalent to the weak form in the distributional sense, and to the integral balance equation.